# Conditional formatting in google sheets to inherit formatting from other cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I've been trying to figure out how to apply conditional formatting to the background of a cell. I've searched the internet but haven't been able to find anything related to this.

I am interested in formatting a cell conditionally, so that if the contents are equal to a text string, the background color will inherit the background color of another cell.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to accomplish it?

This is the quasi-code for the functionality I am looking to achieve:

```
If (cell contents are empty) then
  Apply background from cell offset two cells to the right
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain conditional formatting, you'll need an onEdit function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  if (e.value.length > 0) {
    var reference = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(r.getRow(), r.getColumn()-2)
    var color = reference.getBackground();    
    r.setBackground(color);      
  } else {
    r.setBackground("white"); 
  }
}
```

Note that this will not update the cell's background color when you change the reference cell's background color.